# What is the usefulness of setting custom parameters to Django formset

Tags: django-forms

I was reading through the documents on forms and formset when I came across customizing formset and form's **init** parameters. I quiet get the concept but I don't know any real life application of setting a custom parameters. Someone please broaden this for me.

I tried looking into some questions asked concerning custom parameters here on Stack overflow, I get the concept but I don't know any real application of passing custom parameters to forms and formsets

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a game where a player can choose to attack his neighbors. Obviously every player has different neighbors. Every neighbor is also a player. For the attack-move the player needs to choose one neighbor out of these four.

Basically your form needs a dynamic `ModelChoiceField`. Dynamic hence every player has different neighbors.

```py
class AttackForm(forms.Form, BaseForm):

    def __init__(self, neighbor_queryset, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['neighbors'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=neighbor_queryset,
            widget=forms.Select()
        )
```

This allows you to pass the `neighbor_queryset` on the fly to the form. See another example for `ModelChoiceField` ([here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships)). They did not explicitly put `queryset` in the arguments of `__init__`, therefore you have to `pop()` it from the kwargs.

Comment: But sir I have a question. I am experiencing a osError (errno 38) with an ImageField of the model that I created days ago. I goggle searched everywhere but I can't find any solution, like the problem is my phone related. I am using an Android phone version of 10.0